# Placing a button at the bottom of a collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a collectionView that shows 10 item at first, when scrolling to the bottom I want to have a button that clicking it will load more info, its something simple but the thing is that I'm not using storyboard and I did everything programmatically, so how it can be done?

Comment: Have you tried any solution to your problem? Can you share your code with us?

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView. So you need to:

1. Add your button as subview of your UICollectionView
2. Set it's frame in the way you prefer (if you count your frames in code - just set it manually) based on `.contentSize` of you UICollectionView.
3. Set `.contentInset.bottom` property based on the height of your button/footer
4. You need to handle the case when `.contentSize` changes. If your button should be visible all the time, maybe better to set your button frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function
5. If you want to show/hide it in some cases, you can animate it using `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` by setting `.contentInset.bottom` in the block